# I saw some interesting code from a colleague. I am a but confused what 's happens. Which standard is it? I failed to find the answer in GOOGLE

Tags: c

Will the line with the comment work? Which output will the line produce

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    struct a{
    int b;
    int c;
};

    printf("%ld\n", sizeof(struct a) * 8 * 8);

    printf("%ld\n", sizeof(struct a[8][8]) ); // <-- can anybody to explain it?

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The question is "will the line work or will it not", and the answer is *it depends*.

`sizeof (struct a[8][8])` will most certainly work. It will tell the size of an array of eight arrays of eight `struct a`; and will evaluate to the same number as `sizeof (struct a) * 8 * 8`, which has the type `size_t` which is an unsigned integer type.

What won't necessarily work is printing the `size_t` value with `%ld`. `%ld` expects the corresponding argument to be `signed long`, but `size_t` is unsigned, and not necessarily of the same size; passing `size_t` as an argument corresponding to `%ld` *might* cause undefined behaviour if `size_t` is defined as some other type. For example on 64-bit Windows `size_t` is 64-bit `unsigned long long` whereas `unsigned long` is only 32 bits wide.

The proper conversion setting in C is `%zu`, where `z` means `size_t`/`ssize_t` and `u` unsigned decimal number. Thus the correct program would be

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    struct a{
       int b;
       int c;
    };

    printf("%zu\n", sizeof (struct a) * 8 * 8);
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof (struct a[8][8]));
    return 0;
}
```

Both shall produce the same value, the most common value would be nowadays 512, but could be some other multiple of 64 from 128 upwards, depending on the targeted architecture...

Comment: There isn’t a problem in fitting in an int variable the value of another with size_t, defined behavior as long as the actual VALUE contained in the size_t variable doesn’t exceed the maximum value an int can hold. Only when it exceeds you have undefined behavior. 

That doesn’t invalidate the point that is best practice to use the same types, unless there’s a compelling reason not to do it.

Comment: @abetancort: the program does not attempt to store the size in an integer variable, which as you say would be fine unless the value exceeded the maximum value for that integer type. The problem is that it uses the wrong `printf` conversion, which is UB regardless of the value being printed.

Comment: @rici within printf function itself when a %d is is found in its first argument, the value of the argument that you pass corresponding to the %d is assured to be retrieved by the function to a signed type with at least precision equal to that of an integer. Your will get a compiler warning of a type mismatch but no compiler error and will execute with no errors or incorrect results.

Comment: @abetancort that's not really how it works.

Comment: @antii I truly believe as that it really uses the higher precision *long*. But you if you explain me how you think it actually works, I am willing to consider it.

Comment: @abetancort: arguments to a function are placed between registers and the stack using a complicated algorithm based on the types of the arguments. For a variadic function, since there is no type declared in the prototype, the arguments are submitted to arithmetic promotion (if narrower than `int`/`double`) and otherwise left unaltered. The called function must, therefore, know the actual type of its arguments in order to look for them in the right place. That's why it's required that printf conversions indicate the actual type of the arguments.

Comment: ...So if you specify `%d` and the actual argument is wider than `%d`, not only will `printf` look in the wrong place for that argument (or, at best, use only some of the bytes of its representation), but also it will look in the wrong place for the *next* argument. Needless to say, this is Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: @abetancort As rici said, though they're called **default argument promotions**.

Comment: @rici and Antti  I stand corrected. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

C 2018 6.7.7 2 says it well: “In several contexts, it is necessary to specify a type. This is accomplished using a *type name*, which is syntactically a declaration for a function or an object of that type that omits the identifier.”

So, consider that you would declare a `struct a` named `x` using `struct a x`, and you would declare an array of eight arrays of eight `struct a` named y using `struct a y[8][8]`. The type name is simply such a declaration with the name removed, `struct a` or `struct a [8][8]`.

The removal of the space to make `struct a[8][8]` is misleading; it deceives the eye about where the identifier would go. It is accepted by the compiler since the C syntax and grammar are flexible about spaces, but `struct a [8][8]` is a better representation of the grammatical structure of the declaration.

So, now we see that `sizeof(struct a[8][8])` is simply the size of an array of eight arrays of eight `struct a`, so it is eight times eight times the size of a `struct a`.

In the C standard grammar, the token for this is a *type-name*, and it appears in casts, `sizeof` operands, and operands of `_Generic`, `_Atomic`, and `_Alignof`.

Note `sizeof` produces value of type `size_t`, and this should be formatted with `%zu`, not `%ld`.